# Can I use a router to distribute an internet connection from a laptop?

Tags: windows, networking, router, bridge, signal

I want to take the signal from one router, using a laptop. From this laptop, send it to another router, and distribute the aforementioned signal throughout another wireless network. I even have a diagram for you guys cause its confusing to put it into words.

[image]

Please let me know.

Comment: Please let us know what your end goal is. TCP/IP has a multicast address feature which will allow your routers to broadcast into more than one subnet. If you are trying to set up a server for broadcasting media to a large number of users on a wireless network, I recommend XBMC (runs on Linux) with little overhead.

Comment: If you can gives us the details or specs of the devices that you would be using for this setup then we might be able to guide you more precisely. Your laptop's OS, the details of the two router that you would be using are essential ones.

Comment: Can the LAPTOP run Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

What your asking to do is bridge your connection, there's a good write up on Microsoft's website [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7), and here's a simpler explanation in video form [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8z3V8LJIy8g). And plug the ethernet cord into the router in one ethernet ports on the back of the second router where you would usually plug in a modem, it's usually a yellow colored port.

Additionally and again depending on your router you should disable the DCHP server on it, this can be done manually or by enabling it as a "Wireless Access Point" in the router's settings.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted this because the answer is probably wrong - you need to route the traffic otherwise you could have conflicts with subnets and you will be wasting an aweful lot of bandwidth by redistributing traffic which should not be redistributed.  Router to Router communications should be done using routing where the routers are not all peers (and it seems the second router is not a peer)

Answer (score 0):

You could just run the Ethernet cable between the two routers to give router #2 internet access from router #1 (plug one end of the Ethernet cable into the "WAN" port on the router #2, and the other end into a numbered port on router #1).

Another option is to turn your laptop into a "hot-spot" (wireless access point) by putting the Ethernet cable between router #1 (in your diagram, instead of router #2) and the laptop - this will (obviously) give your laptop internet.  Then from there, you can turn your laptop into a wireless hot spot by using Linux or some third party software on Windows (or maybe internet connection sharing).

To do it the way you have in your diagram may be possible, but would definitely require a lot more work than what I just described.  You could also check to see if both routers support "bride mode", which allows you to bridge them together wirelessly (check the firmware).